# jboss 6.3 management application does not recognize mysql driver

Tags: mysql, jboss6.x

Using the built-in management application:

1 - under "runtime/ manage deployments" i add mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar

2 - enable it.

3 - under "configuration/datasources" when i try to add a new datasource, mysql driver does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

In EAP 6, the preferred approach is installing a JDBC driver as a core module.
You can find datasource example configurations for several databases in [EAP 6 Administration and Configuration Guide - 6.8. Example Datasources](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html-single/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/index.html#sect-Example_Datasources).

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded v 5.1.40 and got the problem solved. Maybe jboss isn't as robust as one might think...